# Tensorflow save/load frozen tf.graph and run classification on loaded graph

Tags: python, tensorflow

as I have mentioned in the topic I would like to save my tf.graph into a frozen_graph.pb file. This should save space later I will try to run it an a jetson tx2. I have made a short MNIST example describing my problem. I run tf 1.7 on python 3.5.

Question1: As far as I understood my freeze_graph method takes a checkpoint file transfers all variables to constants except the ones i define with the second parameter. When I try to get the correct tensorname I wrote loggits.name but I get an error no Tensor with that name found in graph.

Question2: After that I would be able to extract a frozen graph, how can i load it back and run an classification on that.

My Code is attached and should work in a single py file. 
Thank you very much in advance

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import os
import time

import tensorflow as tf
import os
import argparse


#METHODS I WANT TO TEST
#TAKE THE CHECKPOINT FILE AND DELETE ALL NOTES THAT ARE NOT USEFUL
def freeze_graph(checkpoint_directory,output_node_names):
    #checkpoint = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(checkpoint_directory)
    print(checkpoint_directory)
    checkpoint = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(checkpoint_directory)
    input_checkpoint = checkpoint.model_checkpoint_path
    absolute_model_dir = str(os.sep).join(input_checkpoint.split(os.sep)[:-1])
    output_graph = absolute_model_dir + "/frozen_model.pb"
    clear_devices = True

    with tf.Session(graph = tf.Graph()) as sess:
        #import the metagraph in default graph
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(input_checkpoint + '.meta',clear_devices=clear_devices)

        #restore the weights
        saver.restore(sess,input_checkpoint)

        #wrap variables to constants
        [print(n.name) for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node]
        output_graph_def = tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(sess, tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def(),output_node_names.split(","))

        with tf.gfile.GFile(output_graph, "wb") as f:
            f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
        print("%d ops in the final graph." %len(output_graph_def.node))

    return output_graph_def



#HERE IS THE METHOD THAT ALLOWS ME TO LOAD MY FROZEN GRAPH AS GRAPH
def load_graph(frozen_graph_filename):
    with tf.gfile.GFile(frozen_graph_filename,"rb") as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

    with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name = "prefix")
    return graph


#get the data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/",one_hot=True)

#NETWORK PARAMETERS
learning_rate = 0.01

dropout = 0.75
display_step = 1
filter_height = 5
filter_width = 5
depth_in = 1
depth_out1 = 64
depth_out2 = 128

#PARAMETERS OF THE DATASET
input_height = 28
input_width = 28
n_classes = 10

#TRAINING PARAMETERS
epochs = 1
batch_size = 256
num_batches = int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,28*28],name = "input")
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,n_classes])
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

weights = {'wc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([filter_height,filter_width,depth_in,depth_out1])),
           'wc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([filter_height, filter_width, depth_out1, depth_out2])),
           'wd1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([int(input_height/4)*int(input_height/4)*depth_out2,1024])),
           'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024,n_classes]))}

biases = {'bc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([depth_out1])),
          'bc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([depth_out2])),
          'bd1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024])),
          'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}


#DEFINE YOUR NEURAL NETWORKS LAYER OPERATIONS
def ops_conv2d(x,W,b,strides = 1, add_bias = True, activation = tf.nn.relu, use_activation = True):

    x = tf.nn.conv2d(x,W,strides = [1,strides,strides,1],padding = 'SAME')
    x = tf.nn.bias_add(x,b)
    if use_activation:
        return activation(x)
    else:
        return x

def ops_maxpool2d(x,stride=2):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x,ksize=[1,stride,stride,1],strides = [1,stride,stride,1], padding = 'SAME' )

def ops_dropout(input_fully_connected,dropout):
    return tf.nn.dropout(input_fully_connected,dropout)

def ops_fullyconnected(input, activation = tf.nn.relu, use_activation = True):
    fc = tf.reshape(input,[-1,weights['wd1'].get_shape().as_list()[0]])
    fc = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc,weights['wd1']),biases['bd1'])
    if use_activation:
        return activation(fc)
    else:
        return fc

#DEFINE NETWORK ARCHTEKTURE (FORWARDPASS)

def build_network(x,weights,biases,dropout):
    x = tf.reshape(x,shape=(-1,28,28,1))

    conv_layer_1 = ops_conv2d(x,weights['wc1'],biases['bc1'],activation=tf.nn.relu, use_activation=True)
    conv_layer_1 = ops_maxpool2d(conv_layer_1,2)

    conv_layer_2 = ops_conv2d(conv_layer_1,weights['wc2'],biases['bc2'],activation=tf.nn.relu, use_activation=True)
    conv_layer_2 = ops_maxpool2d(conv_layer_2,2)

    fc1 = ops_fullyconnected(conv_layer_2, activation=tf.nn.relu, use_activation=True)
    fc1 = ops_dropout(fc1,dropout)

    logits = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1,weights['out']),biases['out'],name = "logits")

    return logits

#DEFINE TENSORFLOW BACKPROPAGATION OBJECTS (BACKWARDPASS)

logits = build_network(x,weights,biases,keep_prob)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = logits,labels = y))

#CHOSE AN OPTIMIZER
optimizer = tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(loss=loss)
predicted_labels = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits,1),tf.argmax(y,1))

#EVALUATION PARAMETERS
acc = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(predicted_labels,tf.float32))

#NOW INITIALIZE ALL TF VARIABLES
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=10)



#NOW START THE SESSION AND EXECUTE THE GRAPH
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    for i in range(epochs):
        save_path = saver.save(sess, os.curdir + "checkpoints/MNIST_TEST.ckpt")
        for j in range(num_batches):
            batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x:batch_x,y:batch_y,keep_prob:dropout})

            losses,accs = sess.run([loss,acc],feed_dict={x:batch_x,y:batch_y,keep_prob:1.})

            if epochs % display_step == 0:
                print("EPOCH:",'%04d' % (i+1),
                      "loss =", "{:.9f}".format(losses),
                      "acc =", "{:.5f}".format(accs))
    print("TRAINING COMPLETED")
    #START PREDICTIONS
    predicted_label = sess.run(logits,feed_dict={x:mnist.test.images[:256],keep_prob:1.})
    test_classes = np.argmax(predicted_label,1)
    print("TEST ACCURACY:",sess.run(acc,feed_dict={x:mnist.test.images[:256], y:mnist.test.labels[:256],keep_prob:1.}))
    f,a = plt.subplots(1,10,figsize = (10,2))

    for i in range(10):
        a[i].imshow(np.reshape(mnist.test.images[i],(28,28)))
        print( test_classes[i])

    print("TOTAL EXAMPLE FINNISHED")

    freeze_graph(os.curdir + "checkpoints" + os.sep, logits.name)

graph = load_graph(os.curdir + os.sep + "checkpoints" + os.sep + "frozen_model.pb")
with tf.Session(graph) as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    predicted_label = sess.run(logits, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images[:256], keep_prob: 1.})
    print(predicted_label)
```

Answer (score 2):

if anybody has the same problem here is a description how i solved it.
Saving and Loading the data:

First of all note that I have now a different pipeline. First of all I save the session in a saver (ckpt files). Afterwards I construct a metagaph (graph.pb). This graph is then transfered into a frozen graph (frozen.pb). To load the frozen graph I use the load_frozen_graph_from_session method. Inside that method I also test a forward pass through my network.

Running an inference on the loaded graph:
First I name my tensors x (name = "input") this will result in a tensorname ("input:0")
so when you try to fill this placeholder in the new session you need         `predicted_label = sess.run("output:0", feed_dict={"input:0":mnist.test.images[:256], "keep_prob:0": 1.})`

The output is the logit and not the prediction inside my network. This is because if you run the session it will run until it hits the variable you want to fetch. would I take the prediction I need also the placeholder for my y (name=label).

Here is the full code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import os
import time

import tensorflow as tf
import os
import argparse
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile
from tensorflow.python.framework.graph_util import convert_variables_to_constants



#METHODS I WANT TO TEST
def freeze_graph_from_Session(sess,saver):
    # convert_variables_to_constants(sess, input_graph_def, output_node_names, variable_names_whitelist=None)
    save_graph(sess,saver)

    with gfile.FastGFile("./tmp/" + "graph.pb", 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

    frozen_graph_def = convert_variables_to_constants(sess, graph_def, ["output"])

    with tf.gfile.GFile("./tmp/" + "frozen.pb", "wb") as f:
        f.write(frozen_graph_def.SerializeToString())

def save_graph(sess, saver):
    saver.save(sess, "./tmp/model", write_meta_graph=True, global_step=1)

    with open("./tmp/" + "graph.pb", 'wb') as f:
        f.write(sess.graph_def.SerializeToString())
    #sess.close()

def load_frozen_graph_from_session():
    filename = "./tmp/" + "frozen.pb"
    print("LOADING GRAPH")
    with tf.gfile.GFile(filename, "rb") as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

    print("OPEN GRAPH")
    with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
        print("DEFINE INPUT")
        new_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 28 * 28], name="new_input")
        print("DEFINE INPUT MAP")
        tf.import_graph_def(
            graph_def,
            # usually, during training you use queues, but at inference time use placeholders
            # this turns into "input
            input_map={"input:0": new_input},
            return_elements=None,
            # if input_map is not None, needs a name
            name="bla",
            op_dict=None,
            producer_op_list=None
        )

    checkpoint_path = tf.train.latest_checkpoint("./tmp/")

    with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(checkpoint_path + ".meta", import_scope=None)
        saver.restore(sess, checkpoint_path)
        print("TRY FORWARD RUN THROUGH LOADED GRAPH")

        predicted_label = sess.run("output:0", feed_dict={"input:0":mnist.test.images[:256], "keep_prob:0": 1.})
        print("output", predicted_label)
        f, a = plt.subplots(1, 10, figsize=(10, 2))
        test_classes = np.argmax(predicted_label, 1)
        for i in range(10):
            a[i].imshow(np.reshape(mnist.test.images[i], (28, 28)))
            print(test_classes[i])
        print ("output:", test_classes)


#TAKE THE CHECKPOINT FILE AND DELETE ALL NOTES THAT ARE NOT USEFUL
def freeze_graph(checkpoint_directory,output_node_names):
    #checkpoint = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(checkpoint_directory)
    print(checkpoint_directory)
    checkpoint = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(checkpoint_directory)
    input_checkpoint = checkpoint.model_checkpoint_path
    absolute_model_dir = str(os.sep).join(input_checkpoint.split(os.sep)[:-1])
    output_graph = absolute_model_dir + "/frozen_model.pb"
    clear_devices = True

    with tf.Session(graph = tf.Graph()) as sess:
        #import the metagraph in default graph
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(input_checkpoint + '.meta',clear_devices=clear_devices)

        #restore the weights
        saver.restore(sess,input_checkpoint)

        #wrap variables to constants
        [print(n.name) for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node]
        output_graph_def = tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(sess, tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def(),output_node_names.split(","))

        with tf.gfile.GFile(output_graph, "wb") as f:
            f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
        print("%d ops in the final graph." %len(output_graph_def.node))

    return output_graph_def

#HERE IS THE METHOD THAT ALLOWS ME TO LOAD MY FROZEN GRAPH AS GRAPH
def load_graph(frozen_graph_filename):
    with tf.gfile.GFile(frozen_graph_filename,"rb") as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

    with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name = "prefix")
    return graph


#get the data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/",one_hot=True)
print(mnist.test.labels[:256])

print("load_freeze_graph_from_session: STARTED")
load_frozen_graph_from_session()
print("load_freeze_graph_from_session: ENDED")
exit()

#NETWORK PARAMETERS
learning_rate = 0.01

dropout = 0.75
display_step = 1
filter_height = 5
filter_width = 5
depth_in = 1
depth_out1 = 64
depth_out2 = 128

#PARAMETERS OF THE DATASET
input_height = 28
input_width = 28
n_classes = 10

#TRAINING PARAMETERS
epochs = 1
batch_size = 256
num_batches = int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,28*28],name="input")

y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,n_classes],name = "label")
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,name = "keep_prob")

weights = {'wc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([filter_height,filter_width,depth_in,depth_out1])),
           'wc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([filter_height, filter_width, depth_out1, depth_out2])),
           'wd1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([int(input_height/4)*int(input_height/4)*depth_out2,1024])),
           'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024,n_classes]))}

biases = {'bc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([depth_out1])),
          'bc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([depth_out2])),
          'bd1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024])),
          'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}


#DEFINE YOUR NEURAL NETWORKS LAYER OPERATIONS
def ops_conv2d(x,W,b,strides = 1, add_bias = True, activation = tf.nn.relu, use_activation = True):

    x = tf.nn.conv2d(x,W,strides = [1,strides,strides,1],padding = 'SAME')
    x = tf.nn.bias_add(x,b)
    if use_activation:
        return activation(x)
    else:
        return x

def ops_maxpool2d(x,stride=2):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x,ksize=[1,stride,stride,1],strides = [1,stride,stride,1], padding = 'SAME' )

def ops_dropout(input_fully_connected,dropout):
    return tf.nn.dropout(input_fully_connected,dropout)

def ops_fullyconnected(input, activation = tf.nn.relu, use_activation = True):
    fc = tf.reshape(input,[-1,weights['wd1'].get_shape().as_list()[0]])
    fc = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc,weights['wd1']),biases['bd1'])
    if use_activation:
        return activation(fc)
    else:
        return fc

#DEFINE NETWORK ARCHTEKTURE (FORWARDPASS)

def build_network(x,weights,biases,dropout):
    x = tf.reshape(x,shape=(-1,28,28,1))

    conv_layer_1 = ops_conv2d(x,weights['wc1'],biases['bc1'],activation=tf.nn.relu, use_activation=True)
    conv_layer_1 = ops_maxpool2d(conv_layer_1,2)

    conv_layer_2 = ops_conv2d(conv_layer_1,weights['wc2'],biases['bc2'],activation=tf.nn.relu, use_activation=True)
    conv_layer_2 = ops_maxpool2d(conv_layer_2,2)

    fc1 = ops_fullyconnected(conv_layer_2, activation=tf.nn.relu, use_activation=True)
    fc1 = ops_dropout(fc1,dropout)

    logits = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1,weights['out']),biases['out'],name = "output")

    return logits

#DEFINE TENSORFLOW BACKPROPAGATION OBJECTS (BACKWARDPASS)

logits = build_network(x,weights,biases,keep_prob)
#freeze_graph(os.curdir + "checkpoints" + os.sep, logits.name)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = logits,labels = y))

#CHOSE AN OPTIMIZER
optimizer = tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(loss=loss)
predicted_labels = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits,1),tf.argmax(y,1))

#EVALUATION PARAMETERS
acc = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(predicted_labels,tf.float32))

#NOW INITIALIZE ALL TF VARIABLES
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=10)



#NOW START THE SESSION AND EXECUTE THE GRAPH
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    for i in range(epochs):
        save_path = saver.save(sess, os.curdir + "checkpoints/MNIST_TEST.ckpt")
        for j in range(num_batches):
            batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x:batch_x,y:batch_y,keep_prob:dropout})

            losses,accs = sess.run([loss,acc],feed_dict={x:batch_x,y:batch_y,keep_prob:1.})

            if epochs % display_step == 0:
                print("EPOCH:",'%04d' % (i+1),
                      "loss =", "{:.9f}".format(losses),
                      "acc =", "{:.5f}".format(accs))
    print("TRAINING COMPLETED")
    #START PREDICTIONS
    predicted_label = sess.run(logits,feed_dict={x:mnist.test.images[:256],keep_prob:1.})
    test_classes = np.argmax(predicted_label,1)
    print("TEST ACCURACY:",sess.run(acc,feed_dict={x:mnist.test.images[:256], y:mnist.test.labels[:256],keep_prob:1.}))
    f,a = plt.subplots(1,10,figsize = (10,2))

    for i in range(10):
        a[i].imshow(np.reshape(mnist.test.images[i],(28,28)))
        print( test_classes[i])

    print("TOTAL EXAMPLE FINNISHED")

    #freeze_graph(os.curdir + "checkpoints"+os.sep,logits)
    print("freeze_graph_from_session: STARTED")
    freeze_graph_from_Session(sess,saver)
    print("freeze_graph_from_session: ENDED")

print("load_freeze_graph_from_session: STARTED")
load_frozen_graph_from_session()
print("load_freeze_graph_from_session: ENDED")

#with tf.Session() as sess:
#
#    sess.run(init)
#    graph = load_graph(os.curdir + os.sep + "checkpoints" + os.sep + "frozen_model.pb")
#    predicted_label = sess.run(logits, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images[:256], keep_prob: 1.})
#    print(predicted_label)
```

Thanks goes out to my self. :)